# How to use bash pipe with perl script

Tags: linux, perl

I need to run this command using perl script using system.This code line is not working.do you have any idea why

```
system("ping -w 300  -i $interval $host \|  sed 's/\(.*\)/\$(date +%F\ %T) \1/g' >> $ test" )
```

Comment: Quoting will be your problem. Just use `Net::Ping` and do the work within `perl`

Comment: "This code line is not working" is not an adequate description on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is rife with code injection bugs.

Using localtime for timestamps without including time zone information (e.g. an offset from UTC) is problematic in places with daylight saving time.

Here's a solution that addresses those problems:

```
use POSIX              qw( strftime );
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

open(my $fh_log, '>>', $test)
   or die $!;

open(my $pipe, '|-', "ping", "-w", "300", "-i", $interval, "--", $host)
   or die $!;

while (<$pipe>) {
   my $ts = strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", localtime);
   print($fh_log "[$ts] $_");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
my $ping_check =`ping -w 300  -i $interval $host | while read line; do echo \`date \+%F%T\` - \$line >> $logfile; done `;
```

using this code line i was able to get what i need

Comment: Wow, that looks awful (and probably suffers from command injection).